# Error When using "make" for mod_wsgi 3.3

Tags: python, apache, mod-wsgi

I am getting the following error when trying to run `make` on mod_wsgi 3.3 compilation on CentOS x86_64:

```
/usr/local/include/python2.6/pyport.h:694:2: error: #error "LONG_BIT definition
  appears wrong for platform (bad gcc/glibc config?)."
```

Setup Info:

My configure script:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local  --with-python=/usr/local/bin/python2.6
  --with-apxs=/usr/sbin/apxs
```

make:

```
LD_RUN_PATH=/usr/local/lib make

file /usr/local/bin/python2.6:
/usr/local/bin/python2.6: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, AMD x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), for GNU/Linux 2.6.9, dynamically linked (uses shared libs), not stripped
file /usr/sbin/httpd:
/usr/sbin/httpd: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, AMD x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), for GNU/Linux 2.6.9, stripped
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Your Python installation appears to not have been installed properly for both 32 bit and 64 bit.

Comment: Please only post an answer on either site. I'm just posting here in case some one else may want to answer too.  I appreciate the help.                                                                     
-  I have been using this configure script, part of which is from linuxfromscratch.com:

sed -i "s/ndbm_libs = \[\]/ndbm_libs = ['gdbm', 'gdbm_compat']/" setup.py && ./configure --prefix=/usr/local --enable-shared --with-threads       

   - I am running 64 bit apache.  Should I be adding an flag/option for 64 bit in my configure script for python?  If yes, do you know what those options are?

Comment: Configure:                                                                   sed -i "s/ndbm_libs = []/ndbm_libs = ['gdbm', 'gdbm_compat']/" setup.py && ./configure --prefix=/usr/local --enable-shared --with-threads